# ORACLE SQL - Count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following schema in Oracle DB:

```
create table DVD (
  dvdID         char(25) not null,
  datePurchased DATE not null,
  filmID        char(25) not null,

  PRIMARY KEY (dvdID),
  FOREIGN KEY (filmID) REFERENCES Film(filmID)
);

create table MonthlyStatement(
  customerID   char(25) not null, 
  dvdID        char(25) not null,
  dateHired    DATE not null,
  dateReturned DATE,

  PRIMARY KEY (dvdID, customerID, dateHired),
  FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES Customer(customerID),
  FOREIGN KEY (dvdID) REFERENCES DVD(dvdID)
);

insert into MonthlyStatement values ('0001','0005','06-oct-2015',null);
insert into MonthlyStatement values ('0001','0006','06-oct-2015','11-oct-2015');
insert into MonthlyStatement values ('0002','0002','02-sep-2015','12-sep-2015');
insert into MonthlyStatement values ('0002','0003','02-sep-2015','12-sep-2015');
insert into MonthlyStatement values ('0003','0018','06-oct-2015','12-oct-2015');
insert into MonthlyStatement values ('0004','0041','02-oct-2015','09-oct-2015');
```

I have the following description to make a query for:

List all DVDs that were hired in October 2015 (including those that were not returned in October). For each DVD, list its unique number and the number of times it was hired. Sort the DVDs in ascending order of DVD numbers.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
select * from DVD
inner join MonthlyStatement on DVD.dvdID =MonthlyStatement.dvdID
where to_char(MonthlyStatement.dateHired,'Mon-YYYY')='Oct-2015'
order by DVD.dvdID
```

**COUNT**

```
select DVD.dvdID,DVD.datePurchased,DVD.filmID,Count(MonthlyStatement.dateHired) from DVD
inner join MonthlyStatement on DVD.dvdID =MonthlyStatement.dvdID
where to_char(MonthlyStatement.dateHired,'Mon-YYYY')='Oct-2015'
group by DVD.dvdID,DVD.datePurchased,DVD.filmID
order by DVD.dvdID
```

Comment: Thank you that does work great. But is there way to show the count for each specific DVD? for example have another field called 'Count' that shows how many times the DVD was rented?

Comment: Yes can do that just use group By

Comment: But that will just group them and the user will have to manually count, I need a field to actually show the number. Such as dvdID - 0004, count - 2. dvdID - 0011, count - 4 etc

Comment: When you use group by you can use grouping methods like count .count will do the job

Comment: Thank you, I will accept that. I have also done this way, which works the same. SELECT DVD.dvdID, COUNT(DVD.dvdID) AS TimesHired from DVD
inner join MonthlyStatement on DVD.dvdID =MonthlyStatement.dvdID
WHERE to_char(MonthlyStatement.dateHired,'Mon-YYYY')='Oct-2015'
GROUP BY DVD.dvdID;

Comment: Your code is NLS dependent and will fail for people in different **NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE**.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues.

> '06-oct-2015'

Firstly, `'06-oct-2015'` is not a **DATE**, it is a string. Both are different. You must always use **TO_DATE** to explicitly convert a literal into **DATE** with proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

TO_DATE is NLS dependent. So, you need to take care of the NLS parameters at individual statement level. You could do it at session too.

```
TO_DATE('06-oct-2015','dd-mon-yyyy','nls_date_language=american')
```

When dealing with only date element, i.e. without time element, I prefer the **ANSI Date literal** which follows a **fixed format** `YYYY-MM-DD` and therefore it is **NLS independent**:

```
DATE '2015-10-06'
```

> dvdID char(25)

The **CHAR datatype** stores **fixed-length** character strings. String values will be **space-padded** before being stored on disk which is an inefficient way. It is much more efficient to use the VARCHAR2 data type when storing variable-length strings.

> List all DVDs that were hired in October 2015 (including those that were not returned in October).

It is a simple join of the two tables, and a filter predicate on the `dateHired` column:

```
where to_char(MonthlyStatement.dateHired,'Mon-YYYY','nls_date_language=american')='Oct-2015'
```

Remember, using **TO_CHAR** would suppress any regular index on the column. Either use a **function-based index** or better use a **date_range condition** for better performance which will use the regular index.